# which one is good way to implement Switch Case for below code?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, coding-style, code-cleanup

Most of the place I found use polymorphism instead of Switch case statement. I know it is better to use polymorphism if all the case are different in switch case.

what happen if few cases have same code! which approach is good? polymorphism  or switch case.

for example:

```
QList<QString> ret;
switch (x) 
   { 
       case A1: 
       case A2: ret = QList<QString>() <<"A" <<"B" <<"C" ;
               break; 
       case A3:
       case A4: ret = QList<QString>() <<"E" <<"F" <<"G" << "H" <<"T" ; 
               break; 
       case A5:
       case A6:
       case A7: ret = QList<QString>() <<"H" <<"F" <<"K" << "L" <<"T" ; 
               break; 
       default: ret = QList<QString>(); 
                break;   
   }
```

If I use the polymorphism.

1) If I create the separate class for case A1 - A7 then I may require to create separate copy of QList() in all derive class(A1 - A7). I think It will use more memory space.

I put only example code my code is different.

please anyone suggests me which approach is good for this type of situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Qt containers like `QString` or `QList`  have implicit shared implementation so don't worry about copies of one list (in most cases). Also you can use smart pointer `QSharedPointer`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really about Qt, but rather about OOP programming in general, isn't it?
There is no single universal answer, it depends on the complexity of the code. For your example it looks like `switch` will do, but as complexity increases polymorphism becomes the better choice.

Your case could probably look something like this:

```
              base class containing the List
              /              |             \ 
             /               |              \ 
  intermediate 1-2    intermediate 3-4    intermediate 5-6-7
     /     \              /     \             /   |   \ 
    A1     A2            A3     A4           A5  A6   A7
```

Each intermediate derived class would do the work common to further derived classes.